# How to inherit account analytic default in odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-7, openerp-8

I am trying to inherit `account.analytic.default` in odoo 8 by below code

```
class analytic_default1(osv.osv):
_inherit = "account.analytic.default"

_columns = {
    'x_analytics': fields.many2one('account.account', 'Account'),
}
```

But it is giving me below error

```
    XmlHttpRequestError INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
    <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
    <p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Comment: That is the error in log?

Comment: Please try to use new API (no osv, no _columns,...) and provide the full error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the exact same code as you're running on your server,
your indenting is wrong. Furthermore I'd suggest using the new API.
The code beneath should work without an error.

**old API**

```py
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class analytic_default1(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "account.analytic.default"

    _columns = {
        'x_analytics': fields.many2one('account.account', 'Account'),
    }
```

**new API**

```py
from openerp import fields, models

class AnalyticDefault(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.analytic.default"

    x_analytics = fields.Many2one(
        'account.account',
        'Account'
    )
```

Comment: When my edit is reviewed and accepted there will be much better indentation ;-) ([PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), [Odoo Guidelines](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/guidelines.html))

Comment: And something more: The field shouldn't be named x_analytics, instead use analytic_id or much better account_id (why should there be analytic within the name anyways? @Tahir Noor)

Comment: Its done after restart browser.... No error was there in my code... Thanks